# How to prevent that a variable save data in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm having this problem
I have an input that depending of a `radio` selection it changes into a `type number or date` also a have a select and all of this in my form with a submit button.
The problem is that if a press the first radio and sends data, it works perfectly, but if I chance for the `date type` and go back to the `number type`, it saves the oldest data and also saves the select value, after submitting.
Obsly I'm clearing the inputs after changing from the one tho the other

My view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form_transferencias_enviadas">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Parámetro de impresión</legend>
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="parametro_impresion" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3" id="hasta_hidden" hidden>
        <span>Hasta:</span>
        <input type="date" id="parametro_impresion_hasta">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-2" id="select_hidden" hidden>
        <select id="slc_transferencia_destino" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                                            @foreach($empresas as $empresa)
                                                @if($empresa->nombre!=Auth::user()->activo()->pluck('nombre')->first())
                                                    <option value="{{$empresa->nombre}}">{{$empresa->nombre}}</option>
                                                @endif

                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

My js

```js
//ocultar campos
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="busqueda_radio"]').on('ifClicked', function(event) {
    var num = parseInt(this.value)
    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        $('#select_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#hasta_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#parametro_impresion').prop('type', 'number').val('').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        submit_buton(num)
        break
      case 2:
        $('#select_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#parametro_impresion').prop('type', 'date').val('').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        $('#hasta_hidden').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        submit_buton(num)
        break
      case 3:
        $('#hasta_hidden').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#parametro_impresion').prop('hidden', true).prop('disabled', true)
        $('#select_hidden').prop('hidden', false).prop('disabled', false)
        submit_buton(num)
        break
    }
  })
})


function por_numero(numero_transferencia) {
  console.log(numero_transferencia)
}

function por_fecha(desde, hasta) {
  console.log(desde + ' hasta ' + hasta)
}

function por_destino(destino) {
  console.log(destino)
}

function submit_buton(caso) {
  $('#form_transferencias_enviadas').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    switch (caso) {
      case 1:
        por_numero($('#parametro_impresion').val())
        break
      case 2:
        por_fecha($('#parametro_impresion').val(), $('#parametro_impresion_hasta').val())
        break
      case 3:
        por_destino($('#slc_transferencia_destino').val())
        break

    }
  })
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `submit_buton` you add a new `submit` handler to the form, but you don't remove the old one. So when you submit the form, it runs *all* the submit handlers that you attached.

You should remove the old handler before adding the new one:

```
$('#form_transferencias_enviadas').off("submit").submit(function(e) {
    ...
});
```